# Is it possible to run a program/function written in different language from solidity?

Tags: external-api

I have a script written in a different language to get executed and verified by miners of the network. Is there a way to call this script from solidity smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. No matter what language a contract is written in, it is compiled down to bytecode which follows a specific specification. As long as you know the address of the contract you wish to call, the name of the function, and the details of the arguments, it should not matter which language the contract was originally written in.